# I want to authenticate HOST users inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

Is there a way to authenticate the host os users from docker container ?

Bind mapping the passwd , shadow and pam.d file make it work. 
for example :
-v /etc/pam.d:/etc/pam.d 
-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd 
-v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow

But is there any other feature / way in Docker which makes this possible without doing bind mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who can run Docker commands is root, so it doesn't matter.  As a corollary, if you need to make decisions based on the calling host user, you almost certainly *don't* want your tool packaged in a Docker image.

Put another way: if I can use `docker run -v` to bind-mount the host's `/etc/shadow` into a container for authentication purposes, then I can also `docker run -u root -v /:/host ubuntu sh` and make whatever changes I want to `/host/etc/passwd`, steal and decrypt the root password from `/host/etc/shadow`, add myself to `/host/etc/sudoers`, and so on.